# Show all regex matches from String

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string: `aaabaaa`

I want to match the following pattern: `aba`, `aabaa`, `aaabaaa`

Right now I have the following regex pattern: `/(([a-z])\2*)((?!\2)[a-z])\1/g`

It only matches `aaabaaa` but not the other ones. The pattern has to work for all characters and the characters can be surrounded by other characters.

Works for:

> 'mnonnopoo' -> ['non', 'opo'] 
> 'asasd' -> ['asa']

Doesn't work for:

> 'aaaasaaaaa' -> ['asa', 'aasaa', 'aaasaaa', 'aaaasaaaa'] 
> 'aaabaazsaaasbbabba' -> ['aba', 'aabaa', 'bab', 'bbabb']

[regexr.com/63igv](http://regexr.com/63igv)

Comment: regex never matches multiple times for the same piece of text - i.e. if `aabaa` is matched in `----aabaa----` then it won't also match for `aba` - since `aabaa` is already matched

Comment: Does that mean there is no regex solution for my problem?

Comment: correct, as far as I know the one "slice" of text can only be returned as 1 match, no "sub match" I don't think

Comment: I think it's possible to get the desired result by using recursive patterns in regex. But Javascript's regex engine doesn't support this feature (yet).

Answer (score 0):

As people indicated in the comment, regex don't match multiple times for the same string, not in javascript at least.
If you used the on-greedy regex,

```
/([a-z])((?!\1)[a-z])\1/g
```

it would find

'aaaasaaaaa' -> ['asa']

'aaabaazsaaasbbabba' -> ['aba', 'bab']

So you could use greedy regex

```
/([a-z]*?)((?!\1)[a-z])\1/g
```

Which would leave you with

'aaaasaaaaa' -> ['aaaasaaaa']

'aaabaazsaaasbbabba' -> ['aabaa', 'bbabb']

Then sub the results recursively to make the following regex:

```
 /(?!.*bbabb.*)(?!.*aabaa.*)(?!.*aaaasaaaa.*)([a-z]*?)((?!\1)[a-z])\1/g
```

It then matches 'aaasaaa', 'aba', and 'bab' and you simply keep looping till there is no match.

Though I'm sure there are probably better ways to this without regex.